# How to delete unread items in outlook using code

Tags: c#, vba, outlook, outlook-2007

I have created a rule for transferring some of my mails in let's say folder X. Now from time to time I keep on getting hundreds of mail everyday. Out of this mails, some are important and I read them and save them. The rest I have to delete.Now the catch is on the next day when I receive mails, I'll just read the relevant mail of that day and would like to delete all unread, where the mail I read yesterday and today are not deleted.Is it possible to code something to do this? Is it possible to do it in C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO), more specifically the [Outlook solutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/vsto/dd162450.aspx) you can develop with Visual Studio.

With VSTO you can develop proper add-ins that listens to events etc.